# Fourier series for $f(x) = 0$ when $0 \lt x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $1$ when $\frac{\pi}{2} \lt x \leq \pi$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am trying to compute the Fourier series for $f(x) = 0$ when $0 \lt x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $1$ when $\frac{\pi}{2} \lt x \leq \pi$.

I've gotten $a_o = \frac{1}{2}$ which I hope is right.

I'm trying to calculate $a_n$ and $b_n$ but I'm not sure how to compute the integrals.

I got $a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)dx$

$a_n = \frac{\sin(\pi n)-\sin(\frac{\pi n}{2})}{\pi n}$

$b_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\sin(nx)dx$

$b_n = \frac{-\cos(\pi n) + \cos(\frac{\pi n}{2})}{\pi n}$

I'm not sure how to move from here or if these are even on the right track.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(x)\cos(nx)dx +\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)dx$

Comment: So you have an integral of 0 and an integral of $cos(nx)$. You know those..

Comment: @Paul Yeah. this was actually how i went about it before ending up with $a_n = \frac{\sin(\pi n)-\sin(\frac{\pi n}{2})}{\pi n}$. But how about $b_n$. I've been told it should be zero and I'm not sure how

Comment: For $b_n$ to be 0 you need the even periodic extension of $f(x)$. There is more than one way to extend your $f(x)$ to a periodic function on the real line. You can only find a Fourier series of a periodic function, so you need to say how $f(x)$ is extended periodically. You are implicitly using the extension $f(x) = f(x+\pi)$, a function of period $\pi$ but you could extend it as an odd or even function (of period $2\pi$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We extend the function f on $[-\pi,\pi]$ by defining $f(-x)=f(x)\,\,$.  Using the standard formula for a Fourier series and noticing that

$b_{n}=0$ for all $n$ we get:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}+2\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty }\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)\pi }cos(2k+1)x$

forgive me for any miscalculations!

Comment: This is what I got except the $b_n = 0$ part. I'm kinda stuck there. Also, why do we have to extend the function? Also, my lecturer gave us an answer to verify our work with, and for the $a_n$ part, it says it's supposed to be $(-1)^{k}$ not $(-1)^{k+1}$. That has me stuck as well

Comment: The b's are zero because the function is even. f(x)=f(-x). The k+1 is because we start from k=0. Probably your teacher starts from k=1 but the result is correct in both cases! My answer is correct. Check it for x=0 and x=1.